# PHP INSERT data MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add values into a database (mysql) using a form.
I can connect with the table but the values are not registered, only empty fields.
Everytime I execute, a row of empty files is added to my table.
If anyone can tellme which part of the code have to be modified in order to register the fields of the form and then send this text into the table I would really appreciate!
I have this file(indextodoenuno.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Formulario de Registro</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php
$server="localhost";

// Aqui abajo escribe el nombre de la base de datos.
// Si tu servidor tiene cpanel normalmente va primero tu nombre de username,
// por ejemplo: username_nombredelabasededatos
$database = "cartago_basedepruebas";

// Aqui abajo el nombre de username de la base de datos para acceder a ella.
$db_user = "root";

// Y ahora la contraseña:
$db_pass = "";

// Conexión con el servidor
mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("error1".mysql_error());

// Selección de Base de Datos
mysql_select_db($database) or die ("error2".mysql_error());

mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `cartago_basedepruebas`.`usuarios` (`NOMBRE`, `EMAIL`, `URL`) VALUES ('$_POST[NOMBRE]', '$_POST[EMAIL]', '$_POST[URL]')");
//mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`NOMBRE`, `EMAIL`, `URL`) VALUES ('$_POST[NOMBRE]', '$_POST[EMAIL]', '$_POST[URL]')");


?>





<div class="group">

<form method="POST" action="insertardatosentabla.php">
  <input type="text" name="NOMBRE" id="NOMBRE" />
  <input type="text" name="EMAIL" id="EMAIL" />
  <input type="text" name="URL" id="URL" />
  <center> <input class="form-btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Suscribirse" /></center>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Update:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Formulario de Registro</title>

</head>

<body>

<div class="group">

<form method="POST" action="indextodoenuno3.php">
  <input type="text" name="NOMBRE" id="NOMBRE" />
  <input type="text" name="EMAIL" id="EMAIL" />
  <input type="text" name="URL" id="URL" />
  <center> <input class="form-btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Suscribirse" /></center>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the php file:

```
<?php
$server="localhost";

// Aqui abajo escribe el nombre de la base de datos.
// Si tu servidor tiene cpanel normalmente va primero tu nombre de username,
// por ejemplo: username_nombredelabasededatos
$database = "cartago_basedepruebas";

// Aqui abajo el nombre de username de la base de datos para acceder a ella.
$db_user = "root";

// Y ahora la contraseña:
$db_pass = "";
$NOMBRE= $_POST['NOMBRE'];
$EMAIL= $_POST['EMAIL'];
$URL= $_POST['URL'];
// Conexión con el servidor
mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("error1".mysql_error());

// Selección de Base de Datos
mysql_select_db($database) or die ("error2".mysql_error());

mysql_query ("INSERT INTO usuarios (NOMBRE,EMAIL,URL) VALUES ('".$NOMBRE."', '".$EMAIL."', '".$URL."')");
//mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`NOMBRE`, `EMAIL`, `URL`) VALUES ('$_POST[NOMBRE]', '$_POST[EMAIL]', '$_POST[URL]')");


?>
```

Right now If I execute the php file in cmd:

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: NOMBRE in C:\Users\F80SHV0\Desktop\indextodoenuno3
.php on line 14
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: EMAIL in C:\Users\F80SHV0\Desktop\indextodoenuno3.
php on line 15
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: URL in C:\Users\F80SHV0\Desktop\indextodoenuno3.ph
p on line 16

Comment: Do not use `mysql` library for any (production/playing around) purpose, it has been deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Please, do not use *mysql_*, it is deprecated for long time now and you cannot image how simple it is to hack your website... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I have solved the issue using PDO.

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_query ("INSERT INTO`cartago_basedepruebas`.`usuarios`(`NOMBRE`,`EMAIL`,`URL`) VALUES ('".$_POST[NOMBRE]."', '".$_POST[EMAIL]."', '".$_POST[URL]."')");`

Use this hope will solve your problem

Comment: Do not use `mysql` library for any (production/playing around) purpose, it has been deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: All you did was replace string substitution with concatenation. Why would that fix it?

Comment: cause some time it would take $_POST[] as string i have expreince the same and by doing above thing it solved it which is why i gave the same suggestion

Comment: $_POST[URL] the URL should be within single quotes

Comment: sorry but Ive tried all this and I still have the same problem

Comment: remove the `DB` name i.e. just remove this `cartago_basedepruebas` from the query and run. since you are already connecting to the database while opening a DB connection for running query. Give it a shot hope it might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `cartago_basedepruebas`.`usuarios` (`NOMBRE`, `EMAIL`, `URL`) VALUES ('".$_POST['NOMBRE']."', '".$_POST['EMAIL']."', '".$_POST['URL']."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `cartago_basedepruebas`.`usuarios` 
  (`NOMBRE`,`EMAIL`, `URL`) VALUES ('".$_POST['NOMBRE']."', 
   '".$_POST['EMAIL']."', '".$_POST['URL']."')");
```

use single quote inside any post ['']

Comment: This is incorrect syntax. If you're going to put quotes around the key, you have to wrap in { }, e.g. `"{$_POST['NOMBRE']}"`.

Comment: sorry but Ive tried all this and I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `cartago_basedepruebas`.`usuarios` (`NOMBRE`, `EMAIL`, `URL`) 
VALUES ('".$_POST['NOMBRE']."', '".$_POST['EMAIL']."', '".$_POST['URL']."')");
```

**second Method**

or else store value in variable  and pass it

```
$NOMBRE= $_POST['NOMBRE'];
$EMAIL= $_POST['EMAIL'];
$URL= $_POST['URL'];
```

in MySql

```
VALUES ('$NOMBRE','$EMAIL','$URL')
```

Comment: This is incorrect syntax. If you're going to put quotes around the key, you have to wrap in `{ }`, e.g. "{$_POST['NOMBRE']}".

Comment: sorry but Ive tried all this and I still have the same problem

Comment: try second method i mention above

Comment: I've aso tried and nothing..Do you know how to do it using mysqli or PDO?

Answer (score 0):

You're running the `INSERT` code when you're displaying the initial form, not just when it's submitted. You need to test whether the form was submitted:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $server="localhost";

    // Aqui abajo escribe el nombre de la base de datos.
    // Si tu servidor tiene cpanel normalmente va primero tu nombre de username,
    // por ejemplo: username_nombredelabasededatos
    $database = "cartago_basedepruebas";

    // Aqui abajo el nombre de username de la base de datos para acceder a ella.
    $db_user = "root";

    // Y ahora la contraseña:
    $db_pass = "";

    // Conexión con el servidor
    mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("error1".mysql_error());

    // Selección de Base de Datos
    mysql_select_db($database) or die ("error2".mysql_error());

    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `cartago_basedepruebas`.`usuarios` (`NOMBRE`, `EMAIL`, `URL`) VALUES ('$_POST[NOMBRE]', '$_POST[EMAIL]', '$_POST[URL]')") or die (mysql_error());

}
?>
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your interest. I've tried your code but nothing is added to the db not even empty fields.

Comment: Can you telll me how to do it with mysqli or PDO? Maybe this could work.

Comment: Try adding `or die(mysql_error())` after `mysql_query()`, as shown in my updated answer, to see if you're getting an error from MySQL.